# In sitecore get all child and grand child items using fast query

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

In sitecore i want to get all child and grand child which inherited  form "Industrial Product
template .

Below are the fast query , but its giving error 
Error : End of string expected at position 5.

Fast query:

`_masterdb.SelectItems("query:/sitecore/content/Product Catalog/Industrial/Products/*[@@templatename='Industrial Product']")`

Comment: Please note that "fast" doesn't nescessarely mean fast. You probably want to look into indexing to solve what you need.

Comment: Or since you are using Sitecore 7, use `ContentSearchManager` and [LINQ to Sitecore](http://blog.xcentium.com/2013/11/sitecore-7-linq-to-sitecore-simplified-part-1/) if you don't want to create your own search indexes

Answer (score 7):

Your query is not a fast query, if you use the following query, it worked for me:

```
_masterdb.SelectItems("fast:/sitecore/content/Product Catalog/Industrial/Products//*[@@templatename='Industrial Product']");
```

There are two changes in this query:

- Replace the keyword `query` at the beginning to `fast`. This means that it is not a "normal" Sitecore Query, it becomes a Sitecore Fast Query. Please read [this guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf) for more informations about using fast queries.
- Before selecting your items with `*[@@templatename='Industrial Product']`, I've added a double slash `//`. This means, that it searched recursive for all items with your template. With your query you only search for direct child items.

Also, I would recommend you to using the keyword `@@templateid` instead of `@@templatename`, as [sitecore climber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22059356/2074649) said it's faster and it's also no problem if you rename the template. So your query could look like this at the end:

```
fast:/sitecore/content/Product Catalog/Industrial/Products//*[@@templateid='{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}']
```

Note: This does not only select your children and grand children. This does recursively gives you all items with this template.

Comment: Thanks kevin, your answer is comprehensive and pre-empted my question re what's the difference between a normal query and a fast query.

Comment: @BraveNewMath in most cases fast query is faster, it's a different approach how Sitecore queries the database. A small Google gives me e.g. these links: http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/08/sitecore-fast-query-vs-sitecore-query.html and http://firebreaksice.com/options-for-querying-items-from-sitecore/

Answer (score 6):

This is not fast query, you are using normal query .
Please use something like :

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[] items = 
 database.SelectItems("fast:/sitecore/content/Product Catalog/Industrial/Products//*[@@templateid='yourTemplateId']");
```

Also please use @@templateid not @@templatename, I made some tests and it's faster using @@templateid.

Also have a look [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf) about using FastQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below query

_masterdb.SelectItems("query:/sitecore/content/#Product Catalog#/Industrial/Products//*[@@templatename='Industrial Product']")

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
_masterdb.SelectItems("fast:/sitecore/content/#Product Catalog#/Industrial/Products//*[@@templatename='Industrial Product']")
```

or

```
_masterdb.SelectItems("fast:/sitecore/content/#Product Catalog#/Industrial/Products//*[@@templatename='industrial product']")
```

In some cases, you may need to escape names that contain spaces, such as @#Updated by#.